# GameObject is only rendered when it has a negative z scale

Tags: unity, rendering, camera, projection

I have an orthographic camera that looks like this:

[image: Camera]

I create 2d polygonal meshes that have uniform z values in their vertices. I use Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint() to map these viewpoint vertices to world vertices.

The initial z valueI use for each polygon vertex is 1.0f. When I view my generated polygons, they each have a scale of (1,1,1) and are not being rendered. However, when I set the z value of the scale to any value less than zero, the mesh is rendered.

Could this be an issue with my camera's properties?

Comment: Sounds to me like vertex winding order prpblem

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Unity only render one face of the quad with the default shader (you can test it by moving your camera around). By setting another shader (in your case "Sprite/Default" should do the stuff), it will render both faces.

At least it solved the problem for me.

The reason it work with negative z is that a negative scale will flip the quad (thus exposing the other face to your camera).